# NodeJS Express vhosts and updating app.js

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts

I just set up a NodeJS server and wanted to use the vhost function from Express to allow for easy project setup. I want to be able to create a new directory for a new project without going through the hassle of creating new subdomains etc.

Basically, I want to be able to reach project1 at `node.domain.com/project1` and project2 at `node.domain.com/project2`.

I'm now running `server.js`, which is located in the root (`node.domain.com/server.js`) and contains:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

app
.use(express.vhost('node.domain.com', require('./project1/app.js').app))
.use(express.vhost('node.domain.com', require('./project2/app.js').app))
.listen(3000);
```

It's all working fine, when I go to `node.domain.com/project1` I get the results of `./project1/app.js` but whenever I change something in any of the `app.js` files it requires a restart (`Ctrl+C` followed by `node server.js`) for it to update the changes.

And the contents of app.js are, for example:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = exports.app = express(); 

app.get('/project1', function(req, res){ 
    res.send('Hello World [/project1]');
});
```

Any idea why this is?

A thing to note is that I also run Apache on the same server, and I'm using [this guide](http://www.chrisshiplet.com/2013/how-to-use-node-js-with-apache-on-port-80/) to allow both servers to run on port 80 (but accesible via different subdomains).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I feel dumb now, seems like I need to use something like [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), with its `w` flag.